# Retrieve using CAML the currently published version of a document

Tags: caml-query, publishing-site, versioning

I want retrieve the currently published version of a document from a document library using CAML. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this? I need it to get the currently published version irrespective of draft versions etc.

all the best

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an environment where I can test this but have some suggestions for you.

Run a query to check if `_IsCurrentVersion` is TRUE. This may not relate to published versions but it's worth a try.

Or the following query may be enough:

```
<Where>
    <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString" />
        <Value Type="Text">.0</Value>
    </Contains>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

use CAML builder..for the query
and retrieve it